# Ruby on Rails - Actionpack: wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionpack

I'm facing this problem with Rails and heroku:
On my pc everything works well, but the same application on heroku does not work, because of this error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:180:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

Here I paste the full stack trace:

```
$: heroku run rails console
Running rails console on myapp... up, run.4782
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:180:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:180:in `block in add_template_helper'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:180:in `module_eval'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:180:in `add_template_helper'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `block in helper'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
    from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

I could not figure out what could it be!

Could you give me some help?

Comment: can you post what's in application_controller?

Comment: Very easy application_controller: `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end`

Comment: hm, not much :) Do you include anymodule anywhere in your app?

Comment: No, my app is really simple, I didn't include any module in my app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error indicate that one of the helper files is defined as a class rather than a module.

```
class ApplicationHelper
end

vs.

module ApplicationHelper
end
```